# Why .ssh directory permission need to be 700 for passwordless ssh

Tags: centos, ssh, permissions

I am following the steps [here](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) to SSH without password

In order to login from userA@hostA to userB@hostB, the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` at hostB needs to contains the public key of userA@hostA.

When I first create the .ssh/ when logged in userB@hostB, its permission is **771 or drwxrwxr-x**. Under this permission status, I was not able to ssh from userA@hostA to userB@hostB without password.

But when I `chmod 700 .ssh` on userB@hostB, then I can SSH without password happily.

Can someone explain to me why, by providing less strict permission, passwordless SSH cannot be achieved?

Comment: `drwxrwxr-x` is `775` not `771`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To protect your, because otherwise another user on the system could add his own key to your `authorized_keys` file and impersonate you easily.

Comment: It makes total sense and I feel kind of stupid for asking :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement that the permissions have to be `700`, they just must not be writable by anybody except from the owner. And it has to be owned by yourself or root.

It will only be secure if the above holds for the entire path from the root of the file system to the `authorized_keys` file.

Some distributions by default create files and directories as group writable (with only yourself in the group). But `sshd` doesn't check who is in the group, it just refuses to use `authorized_keys` if the file or the directory is group writable.

I don't know of any good reason for creating files and directories group writable by default. I have never seen problems caused by changing it to only be writable to the owner.